# Limits in two variable with two parameters - Is there any strategy?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, analysis, multivariable-calculus

I have this exercise:
"Find for which positive, real $a$ and $b$, each of these limits exist".$$
\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{|x|^a\cdot|y|^b}{x^{88}+y^{12}}\qquad\lim_{x^2+y^2 \to +\infty}\frac{|x|^a\cdot|y|^b}{x^{88}+y^{12}}
$$
In "1-D" I used to eliminate one of the parameters and solve for the other one, or I was on search of indecision form to apply De l'Hospital…

How can I move in "2-D" case? Is there any "common" strategy to follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the limit exists, then it should be the same no matter what path you approach. So I would try to simplify the expression, so that the denominator depends only on one parameter. So in the first limit, I would use $$x^{44}=r\cos\theta\\y^6=r\sin\theta$$
Then the first limit is $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{|x|^a|y|^b}{x^{88}+y^{12}}=\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{r^{a/44+b/6}}{r^2}\cos^{a/44}\theta\sin^{b/6}\theta$$
Now you want the limit on the right hand side to be $\theta$ independent. You can have $a=b=0$, but then $\lim_{r\to 0}\frac 1{r^2}=\infty$.
The other option would be $$\lim_{r\to 0}r^{a/44+b/6-2}=0$$
This is true if $$\frac a{44}+\frac b6 -2>0$$
I would use a similar approach for the other limit. But the condition is sligtly more complicated, so you might need to split in several cases: 1: $x$ is constant, $|y|\to\infty$, 2: $y$ is constant, $|x|\to\infty$, 3: $|x|,|y|\to\infty$

Comment: But after taking this specific path, how do you verify that the limit is the same for any other path?

Comment: Which specific path? The idea was to be direction independent. I just changed the variables to something similar to polar coordinates

Comment: So, you say the limit (if it exists) must be ZERO because $f(t,0) \equiv 0$ (for example)… did you choose that path because was parameter-independent? I mean, there will be some paths which for some values of $a$ and $b$ approach to $+\infty$. Now, I can understand the limit cannot be $+\infty$ due to that initial path. But if I hadn't thought to such a path, I have to be allarmed by the fact I was choosing some values for $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Right. No matter what path you choose, for a given $a$ and $b$, if the limit exists it must be unique. So you can get some limits for some paths, but they are not universal.